# What is the minimal polynomial of an $8$-th primitive root of unity over $\mathbb{Q}_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}_3$ and $\zeta_8$ a primitive $8$-th root of unity.

> **Question**: What is $\min_K(\zeta_8)$?

I know that the extension $K(\zeta_8)/K$ is unramified of degree $2$, so the degree of the minimal polynomial must be $2$.

I also know that the minimal polynomial must be a divisor of $x^4+1$, the $8$-th cyclotomic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. This polynomial also factorizes in two quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3$ which I checked with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20x%5E4%2B1%20in%20GF%283%29).

Could you please help me advancing with this problem?

Comment: Hensel's lemma for polynomials allows you to lift the factorization in $\mathbb{F}_3$ up to $\mathbb{Q}_3$, $x^4+1 = (x^2+\sqrt{-2}x-1)(x^2-\sqrt{-2}x-1)$. Now you can show directly by the quadratic formula that either field extension contains the other.

Comment: Note that there are four primitive eighth roots of unity, and as Merosity's answer-comment shows, they come in two pairs of conjugates over any field that contains a square root of $-2$ but not any of the eighth roots itself.